# In PHP, how can I log transaction process without making the system slow?

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I am trying to add a logging of a specific transaction process in our system to help us trace where the customer had problem

```
 e.g
 2012-12-11 05:35:11 pm : Chose PayPal as payment method
 2012-12-11 05:38:15 pm : Pay = transaction id: E547HGf915JMN
 2012-12-11 05:44:23 pm : Payment processed PayPal payment status = Completed
 2012-12-11 05:45:17 pm : Saved transaction
 2012-12-11 05:47:22 pm : Redirect = http://domain.com/redirect_url/
```

Should I use logging via text file or MySQL? I'm thinking of using text file as Triggers tend to slow down the database and would be harder to maintain in the long run?

Do you have any suggestions or preferred way of logging events/processes?

Thank you very much.

Comment: unlike the 2 answers below i would log to mysql, the usability far the data far out weighting the insignificant usage costs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience you should have to use `text file` for logging of a specific transaction process because this will be safer and don't create problem on Mysql server.

Comment: Thank you for citing your experience. :)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look to Monolog: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog

You can easily log to streams creating logfiles. However, if you need to change that in the future, you can do it with almost no effort. It´s very easy to install it in your project using composer (http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md).

If you need something very fast, you may create a ram disk and put your logfile in it, or use syslog and ramlog (http://www.tremende.com/ramlog/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Logging to text will definitly use less resources than to mysql.

Check out KLogger. It seems to do the job.

http://codefury.net/2008/07/klogger-a-simple-logging-class-for-php/